# Paste data in vs. into file

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence

I have been teaching others how to use various files, and I always wonder if I am using the correct grammar when I say we need to copy and paste data from one file to another.

So which of these is correct?

1. Copy and paste the data into this sheet/file.
2. Copy and paste the data in this sheet/file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The preposition has a sense of direction that is appropriate to copying data from a source and then moving it to a destination. It is the correct word to use, signifying the destination clearly.

Copy (the source) and paste the data into this file (the destination).

> into = in the direction of something or someone
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/into)

If you say "*copy and paste the data in this file*" it is ambiguous. It may be taken to mean *copy the data that is in the source file*, but does not give a sense of the direction or destination to which the data should go.